# Replace selection using Google Suite API

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to replace a selection with an image using Google Suite API.

I figured that if I can get the index of the selection I can insert an image at that specific index and then remove every selected element. However, I can't seem to get the index working correctly.

I've tried the following, but it only returns -1, even though I'm selecting a word in the middle of the text.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var selection = doc.getSelection();
var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
if(elements.length > 0){
    return elements[0].getStartOffset();
}
```

I've tried searching the documentation, but can't find a solution.

What I want is something like:

```
var selection = doc.getSelection();
selection.replaceWithImage(image);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by moving the position of the cursor to the beginning of the selection. Here is the code commented for others having the same question.

```
 function insertImage(imageURL){
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var UI = DocumentApp.getUi();
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageURL).getBlob();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor();

    /* If cursor is null, there is a selection not a position */
    if(!cursor){
        var selection = doc.getSelection();

        /* Get all elements selected */
        var elements = selection.getRangeElements();

        if(elements[0]){
            var element = elements[0].getElement();
            var index;
            var previousElement = element.getPreviousSibling();
            var fakedElement = false;
            var position;

            /* If the element is type TEXT you can't get index from getChildIndex. */
            if(element.getType().toString() == "TEXT"){
                index = elements[0].getStartOffset();
                if(element.getText() === " "){
                    element = doc.insertParagraph(index, "");
                    fakedElement = true;
                }
            } else {
                index = element.getParent().getChildIndex(element);
            }

            /* If the selected element is an image, we need to append a fake paragraph to keep the cursor poisition. Dont worry, this will be removed later. */
            if(elements.length === 1 && element.getType().toString() == "INLINE_IMAGE"){
                element = doc.insertParagraph(index, "");
                fakedElement = true;
            }

            /* Go through each element and remove it. */
            elements.forEach( function (element, key) {
                var text;
                if(element.getElement().editAsText){
                    if(element.isPartial()){
                        text = element.getElement().editAsText();
                        text.deleteText(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive());
                    } else {
                        doc.appendParagraph(''); // Create empty paragraph since you can't delete last paragraph.
                        text = element.getElement().removeFromParent();
                    }
                } else {
                    element.getElement().removeFromParent();
                }
            });

            if(body.getNumChildren() === 1){
                paragraph = doc.getBody().appendParagraph('');
                position = doc.newPosition(paragraph, 0);
                doc.setCursor(position);
            } else if(element && !element.getParent() && previousElement){
                element = previousElement;
                index = element.getParent().getChildIndex(element);
            } else if(body.editAsText().getText().length === 0){
                paragraph = doc.getBody().appendParagraph('');
                position = doc.newPosition(paragraph, 0);
                doc.setCursor(position);
             } else {
                position = doc.newPosition(element, index);
             }

             if(!position){
                paragraph = doc.getBody().appendParagraph('');
                position = doc.newPosition(paragraph, 0);
                doc.setCursor(position);
             }

            /* Move position of cursor to the new position */
            doc.setCursor(position);

            /* Update cursor variable since its now available */
            cursor = doc.getCursor();

            /* If a placeholder element was created to keep the position, remove it. */
            if(fakedElement){
                element.removeFromParent();
            }
        }
    }

    /* Insert image */
    var image = body.appendImage(blob);
    cursor.insertInlineImage(image);
    image.removeFromParent();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a script which helps me locate things inside of a document. In fact, I used it last night to create an envelope printer script for Google Docs.
Here's a [link](http://jimesteban.com/files/LookingInsideofGoogleDocs.txt) to it. I'm always changing it to fit my particular needs so feel free to have fun with.  It will help you to find images too.